# Paypal checkout callback url to display unique sale id in 1x1 img for tracking

Tags: php, paypal, checkout, paypal-ipn

I've been asked by a client to display:

```
<img src='https://www.trackingserver.com.au/saleServlet?MID=43&PID=55&CRID=&ORDERID=<input orderId!>&ORDERAMNT=<input order amount!>&NUMOFITEMS=1' border='0' width='1' height='1'>
```

on the http://www.clientsite.com.au/paypalsuccess.htm callback url

is there anyway to dynamically fill in the  and  values with values returned by paypal.

The client is currently using Paypal Standard > Add to cart buttons ( https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_paypal_shopping_cart )

I can't see anything there about obtaining values upon redirection... I'd like to just be able to process the request header from Paypal in a php version of paypalsuccess.html and pull out the data in questions. Putting it into the img.

Possible? Where should I look?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you will need to implement PayPal's IPN system.

Read up on it here: https://www.paypal.com/ipn/

Basically you:

1. Write your IPN script.
2. Add that script into every PayPal button (or you can manually set your paypal account to always inform that script of any payments).
3. PayPal will then sent that script a POST message whenever somebody makes a payment. That POST message contains virtually every bit of information that you can see through your PayPal control panel.

Answer (score 0):

You can get data from a complete sale when it transfers back to the site using PDT: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/xcl/rec/pdt-intro-outside

I discourage using it though because an order can be completed on Paypal without ever transferring to the site again. IPN is the most reliable way to receive information about orders: https://www.paypal.com/ipn/

However since IPN is all server side stuff, it won't really help you with your question so you will need to use cURL to touch base with the URL you provided.